# R - subsetting a data frame based on a logical condition referencing a variable column

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a `data frame` with one of the columns populated with `strings`. Some of those strings contain valid decimal numbers whereas others do not. I am trying to leave out the entries that do not have valid decimal numbers in the column (i.e. produce `NA` when converting to `numeric`). The data frame is populated from a CSV file:

```
dFrame = read.csv("filename")
```

This works okay if I hardcode the column name `accidentCount` like this:

```
dFrame[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dFrame$accidentCount))), ]
```

Alas, when the column name is provided as a parameter to this subroutine, the idiom mentioned above won't work.
I tried using `[` instead of the `$`:

```
dFrame[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dFrame[variableName]))), ]
```

but all I get is an empty `data frame`. Is there an easy was of doing that? Thanks.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks a lot, worked great. I am happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Pretty standRd advice for a very common error. Read ?'[['